# Cannot make cl-ppcre work with mulit-line mode

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, cl-ppcre

I have two versions of the word `hi`.

````lisp
(defvar x "```hi```")

(defvar y "```
             hi
           ```")
````

I also have a regex scanner:

```` (defvar scanner (cl-ppcre:create-scanner "```(.*?)```" :multi-line-mode t)) ````

When I regex-replace on x, it returns as it should. but the `multi-line-mode` doesn't seem to work.

````lisp
(cl-ppcre:regex-replace scanner x "\\1") ;; => "hi"

(cl-ppcre:regex-replace scanner y "\\1") ;; => "```
                                                hi
                                                ```"
````

I want everything between "```" to be replaced, irrespective of how many lines the string is.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `(create-scanner ... :multi-line-mode t :single-line-mode t)`

Yes, this is insane.  But it's equivalent to what Perl does: in particular, from [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlre):

> `.` Match any character (except newline)

and the `/s` modifier:

> Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

Comment: Doesn't an embedded modifier also work here, like `(?s)`?
I can confirm it works with `(?i)` for enabling case-sensitivity.

Comment: @Manfred: yes, it probably does.